# Accessing child elements in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, webautomation

I have the below HTML structure

```
<div class ="container" id= "12">
    <div class="details" desc-type= "multiline">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="description"> Some Description </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I scraping this using the below code

```
const SELECTOR =
    "div.container";

const movies = await page.$$eval(
    SELECTOR,
      nodes =>
        nodes.map(element => {
          return {
            movieID: element.getAttribute("id"),
          };
        } )    
    );
```

How can I modify the above code so that I can read `desc-type= "multiline"` and `innerText` of `<div class="description">`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
const movies = await page.$$eval(
    SELECTOR,
      nodes =>
        nodes.map(element => {
          return {
            movieID: element.getAttribute("id"),
            descType: element.querySelector('[desc-type]').getAttribute('desc-type'), 
            description: element.querySelector(".description").innerText
          };
        } )    
    );
```